# How do I prove this statement about permutations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutation-cycles

I have the following problem:

> Let $n\geq 3$. We want to show that the alternating group $A_n$ is generated by cycles of the length $3$. To do so we let $H\subset A_n$ be the subgroup generated by all the cycles $(uvw)$ where u,v,w are pairwise distinct integers in $\{1,...n\}$. The goal is to show that $H=A_n$.

I have just shown that it is enough to show it for $(ab)(cd)$ where $a\neq b, c\neq d$.
Now I need to show what would happen if $\{a,b\}=\{c,d\}$. W.l.o.g. we can assume that $a=c, b=d$ but then $(ab)(cd)=(ab)(ab)=(ab)$ but now I don't see what to say about $(ab)$ I think it should be in $H$. Am I wrong?

Comment: $(ab)(ab) \neq (ab)$. $(ab)(ab)$ is the identity permutation.

Comment: sorry I don't see this, why is it the identity permutation and how do we write the identity permutation in a cycle?

Comment: Start with numbers $1 \ldots 10$ in order. Exchange any two of them. Now exchange the same two numbers again. The result is the same as doing nothing at all.

Comment: and is there a way to write this in a cycle because otherwise I can't show if it is in H or not

Comment: Every group contains the identity element. We wouldn't normally say the identity permutation is a cycle, but I'd say it's the product of an empty set of cycles.

Comment: ah okei makes sense thank you!

Comment: Sorry could I ask you again something small, not really about this exercise. If a have a permutation $$\sigma=(ab)(bd)$$ and I want to write this without cycles so in the "normal" permutation notation, i.e as a matrix, how do I do this? because I think we have $$\sigma=\left(\begin{array}{rrr} a&b\\b&a\end{array}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{array}{rrr} b&d\\d&b\end{array}\right)$$. But then how do I multiply them? I'm bit confused

Comment: A permutation matrix has only $0$ and $1$ as its elements, and both dimensions are the number of things it acts on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrong.

Consider $(ab)(ab)$. For all $x\notin\{ a,b\}$, $x$ maps to $x$ under $(ab)$; as for $a,b$, we have

$$\begin{align}
a&\xrightarrow{(ab)}b\xrightarrow{(ab)}a\\
b&\xrightarrow{(ab)}a\xrightarrow{(ab)}b.
\end{align}$$

Therefore, $(ab)(ab)=e$, not $(ab)$.